# How can I get all transaction for a specific address using Nbitcoin?

Tags: transactions, nbitcoin

How can I get all transactions for a specific address using Nbitcoin?

Comment: I've edited your question to ask for "how", since I am assuming you're looking for instructions. Could you clarify whether you want all transactions sending to an address or also the ones that spend those funds later?

Answer (score 1):

you can't get all the transactions done on an address using just Nbitcoin. you need a block explorer for that. you can check out qbi t, blockcypher etc.

However you can get that using Nbitcoin and Nbxplorer (a simple blockchain tracker that monitors your xpub and addresses) with easy to use api's like getTransactions,  getBalance etc.

https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new QBitNinjaClient("http://api.qbit.ninja/", Network.Main);
var address1 = new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("your --Address", Network.Main);
var balance = await client.GetBalance(address1);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question because of "using Nbitcoin". Furthermore (meanwhile) QBit Ninja is not maintained anymore.